# Unable to find option for self registering in WSO2

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

Im using a 4.0 version of WSO2. I'm able to get the login page, however im unable to get the option for self-registering in the login page. I have setup as mentioned in docs, however unable to identify what am I missing.

[image]

Comment: Did you follow https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.11.0/learn/self-registration-and-account-confirmation/#configuring-self-registration and enabled the user self Registration?

Answer (score 0):

Self register option is available for Developer Portal and not for Publisher and Admin portals. The reasoning behind this is that external users should be able to register under organizations (tenants) and consume the published APIs.

[image]

Self signup is enabled my default for super tenant (carbon.super) in Devportal. For other tenants, you might have to enable this manually. Please refer [2] for more information.

[2] - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/customize-product/customizations/customizing-the-developer-portal/enabling-or-disabling-self-signup/#disabling-self-signup